# How to INSERT VALUES after clicking OK on Confirmation Box

Tags: php, ajax

How can I put the php code in the javascript code so that after the user clicks OK on the confirmation box, then it inserts the values in the database? (the form submits to itself but I havn't provided form code)

Below is whole code:

```
                                    <?php
session_start();

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

              $sql = "INSERT INTO Media (Image, Video, Audio) 
                  VALUES (' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $image ) . "',
    ' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $video ) . "',' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $audio ) . "')";


              mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

?>

<script>

function insertQuestion(form) {  

    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
    var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>");
    var $video = $("<td class='video'></td>");
    var $audio = $("<td class='audio'></td>");

      $tr.append($image);
    $tr.append($video);
    $tr.append($audio);    
    $tbody.append($tr); 

    }

          function showConfirm(){

         var confirmMsg=confirm("Make sure that your details are correct, once you proceed after this stage you would not be able to go back and change any details towards Questions, Options and Answers for your Session." + "\n" + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );

         if (confirmMsg==true)
         {
         submitform();   
     }
}

            function submitform()
            {

        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");

          QandAO.submit();

            }

    </script>

    <body>

    <form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post" >

    <table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="image">Image</th>
    <th class="video">Video</th>
    <th class="audio">Audio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>

<p><input id="submitBtn" name="submitDetails" type="submit" value="Submit Details" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;" /></p>

</form> 

         <script type="text/javascript">

function myClickHandler(){
     if(validation()){
                showConfirm();
     }
}

</script>

    </body>
```

The $action method below is where the form goes depending if there is a match or not between $sessionMinus and $_SESSION['initial_count']. If there is a match, post to create_session2.php else post form to itself.

```
    if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = 'create_session2.php'; 

}else if($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_count']){ 

    $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 

}
```

Comment: You submit the form via AJAX, and have the form handling page return an output to tell if it succeeded or not?

Comment: `var confirmMsg=confirm(Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n" );` without begin `"` before `Are [..]`...

Comment: @GabrielSantos, yeah that was a typo when I typed it in the question, it does begin with " in my application

Comment: Undefined variables `$image`, `$video` and `$audio`...

Comment: @Truth do you know an example of AJAX I can use because I haven't used AJAX before?

Comment: @GabrielSantos I just posted necessary code, I did not post whole code because if I do this then someone will tell me I have posted too much code. Don't worry about the code, all I am asking is how do I INSERT VALUES straight after confirmation is OK because php code can't be used in javascript code. Like Truth mentioned do I meed to use AJAX?

Comment: @user1304197 You'd better make it work using a normal form submit first. You can always add ajax later to make the interaction better if needed.

Comment: No you don't need AJAX. See  @jeroen answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually write php code long with javascript. They both run on different ends php on server side and javascript on client side.

In you form attribute action give a php page name like action= "add.php" and also mention method whether it is a post or get

then at your server make a new file add.php. And write you php code there.

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $username="xxx";
   $password="xxx";
   $database="xxx";

    mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

   @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

           $sql = "INSERT INTO Media (Image, Video, Audio) 
              VALUES (' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $image ) . "',
    ' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['video'] ) . "',' ".   mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['$audio'] ) . "')";


          mysql_query($sql);
      mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

?>
```

You can access form using $_GET or $_POST depending upon method by which you submit your form.

If you need further reference then you can go through this http://coredogs.com/lesson/form-data-php

Best 
Deepak

Comment: Hi, I included my whole code so if you want to look at it properly then you can deepak. I will look through your answer and the manual and see if I can work on this.

Comment: The thing I want to mention though is that I want the values to be inserted into the database but I do not want to navigate the user away from the page they are in. I want the values to be inserted into the database after the confirmation but I want it to allow the users to stay on the same page or navigate to the create_session2.php depending on the form 'action'. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your javascript function to the form onSubmit event handler:

```
<form onsubmit="showConfirm();" ...>
```

And then have your function return the value of `confirmMsg`:

```
function showConfirm() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed?\n" );
}
```

That way, when your confirmation box returns `false`, your form does not get submitted but when it returns `true` it does.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, you have not added the php code to the page containing your form. You need to do that if the form submits to itself:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // your php code
}
else
{
  // your form code
}
```

Now your database code will get executed when a form is posted, and the form will be displayed on a normal get request.

Comment: Hi, I know how to get the confirmation appear after clicking on submit button, I have already done that :) What I meant was that after user clicks OK to confirma, I want the values to be inserted into the database but how do I do this.

Comment: If they click cancel, just return false so it doesn't submit the form (assuming thats what you want).

Comment: @user1304197 That is what will happen automatically if your form gets submitted to the page that contains your php code.

Comment: The confirmation isn't the problem, my question is how do I INSERT VALUES after confirmation box appears and user clicked OK, because I don't think I can put php code in javascript code.

Comment: @user1304197 Just add your php code in the form page between conditionals. I'll add some php code...

Comment: My confirmation works correctly, so with the code you have provided me, where do I put this code? If you give me 10 mins, I will show you my whole code above.

Comment: @user1304197 I have commented in the code where your codes should go.